# Javascript Show/Hide Fixed Elements When Entering and Leaving a Select Tag from iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

What function does javascript use to identify when a select or input tag has been tapped on iOS and exited from the native bottom view? I need to hide my fixed elements so it doesn't get in the way when the native bottom view get's raised up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` method to check when it was modified

```
var select = document.getElementById("elementId");

// runs everytime the selection is changed.
select.onchange = function () {
   // do stuff.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to use jQuery mobile so that you can get cross browser support.

**[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)**